# is there something like tor for VOIP?

Tags: relays

One of the killer applications of tor is the ability to create a new tor circuit at the push of a button. Is there something similar for VOIP where also your dynamic/static IP is exposed in the standard scenario. I do understand that bandwidth requirements as well as latency requirements will be more than a tad higher than browsing web pages.

An ideal tool would be which would be one which can be programmed to change something similar to tor relays with a pre-defined interval, say 30 secs. or so

At the very least, I think somebody should have tried it as proof of concept. If people have, would like to know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is already implemented : a [Torfone](http://torfone.org/) add-on for [TorChat](https://github.com/prof7bit/TorChat)

Answer (score 1):

I started Asterisk VoIP server over OpenVPN in Tor hidden service.
It's working with 1s delay.

First create OpenSSL CA with Easy-RSA or OpenSSL for OpenVPN.

This is OpenVPN server configuration file:

```
tls-server
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
ca /etc/ssl/ca.crt
cert /etc/ssl/server.crt
key /etc/ssl/server.key
dh /etc/ssl/dh2048.pem
topology subnet
server 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
max-clients 100
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log
log /var/log/openvpn.log
log-append /var/log/openvpn-append.log
verb 3
auth SHA512
```

This is OpenVPN client configuration file:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote svntrqfgsa7jgnpm.onion 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca /home/norbert/new/ca.crt
cert /home/norbert/new/demo-alice.crt
key /home/norbert/new/demo-alice.key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
verb 3
socks-proxy 127.0.0.1 9050
remote-cert-tls server
```

This is Asterisk sip.conf configuration file:

```
[general]
transport=udp
port=5060
bindaddr=10.0.0.1
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
allow=gsm
directmedia=no
nat=yes
localnet=10.0.0.0/255.255.0.0

[friends_internal](!)
type=friend
host=dynamic
context=from-internal
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
allow=gsm

[demo-alice](friends_internal)
secret=password

[demo-bob](friends_internal)
secret=password
```

This is Asterisk extensions.conf configuration file:

```
[from-internal]
exten=>6001,1,Dial(SIP/demo-alice,20)
exten=>6002,1,Dial(SIP/demo-bob,20)
```

This is Tor hidden service server torrc configuration file:

```
HiddenServiceDir /usr/local/torhs/winternight/
HiddenServicePort 1194 127.0.0.1:1194
```

This is Tor client configuration file:

```
SOCKSPort 9050
```

That's all. It's working with 1s delay.

Documented in these tutorials:

- [How To setup Asterisk VoIP server over OpenVPN in Tor hidden service on FreeBSD system](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13595/how-to-setup-asterisk-voip-server-over-openvpn-in-tor-hidden-service-on-freebsd)
- https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/59190/

Enjoy. :)